Basic app intent always showing error in Shortcuts app "The action could not run because an internal error occurred."
I have a very basic App Intent extension in my macOS app that does nothing than accepting two parameters, but running it in Shortcuts always produces the error "The action “Compare” could not run because an internal error occurred.".

What am I doing wrong?
struct CompareIntent: AppIntent {
    static let title = LocalizedStringResource("intent.compare.title")
    static let description = IntentDescription("intent.compare.description")
    static let openAppWhenRun = true
    
    @Parameter(title: "intent.compare.parameter.original")
    var original: String
    @Parameter(title: "intent.compare.parameter.modified")
    var modified: String
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result()
    }
}

